# Changing localhost in java

Tags: java, netty

I'm writing simple server using netty. By default I work with him using localhost:8080,
but can I change this to somthingAnother:8080 ? 

I can use only java and I don't know on which OS my program will work.

I can't open hosts.txt file and write new host there by myself.

I tried to use 
     `new InetSocketAddres(String hostname, int port)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostname is, unsurprisingly, the name of the host - the server where your service (in this case netty) runs. By default, the name 'localhost' means 'the machine I'm running on' - so you cannot change where that name points to. However, you can add another name to the machine you're working on using

- the hosts file, which will be local to your machine (that is, the name will be associated with an IP address only on your machine)
- using DNS, which will make the name world-wide, bu it will also require a publicly accessible IP address.

What do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I want to add another name to hosts file.

Comment: On Windows, edit %windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, on Linux edit /etc/hosts.

Comment: No, localhost just means IP address 127.0.0.1 and only processes on the same machine can connect to it.

Comment: Okay thank you. I was thinking that I can do it without editing hosts file. Now i will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind ServerBootsrap to a host name using bind(String hostname, int port) or bind(SocketAddress localAddress) where localAddress = InetSocketAddress(Sttring hostname, int port)

Comment: I tried ChannelFuture f = b.bind("someName",8080).sync(), but it gives me "java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address".

Comment: You should use real resolvable hostname or IP address like this b.bind("10.1.2.3", 8080)